# How to get a point (x or y) of a path in absolute (page) coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I assume that extracted coordinate of the following path would relate exclusively to the "canvas" on which it has been drawn. But how can I get coordinates of this path in relation to the entire page?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello \tikz\path[draw=red](0,0)--(2mm,0); world!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For regular document classes this is straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
Hello \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\path[draw=red](0,0)--(2mm,0) coordinate (x);
\path[overlay] let \p1=($(x)-(current page.south west)$) in \pgfextra{\typeout{x=\x1,y=\y1}};
\end{tikzpicture} world!
\end{document}
```

Note that `calc` is not absolutely needed here but simplifies things IMHO. In this example the absolute page coordinates (relative to the south west anchor of the `current page` node are stored in `\x1` and `\y1` but can be used for anything you want.

For standalone with `varwidth` it is probably more difficult because the page dimensions are not clear at the moment the tikz picture is drawn. Depending on what you really want to do one can find solutions, but the absolute coordinates are not of much use here at the point you may want to learn about them.

Comment: It is going to take two runs anyway.  [remember picture] stores the location of the origin using the aux file AFTER the page is formatted.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, sure. Since I chose to report the values via `\typeout` there is not a big chance that this can be missed, one gets asked to recompile the file. But it still returns unrealistic values for `varwidth`, regardless of how often you compile. Of course you can add another mark at the south east anchor of the letter `H`, then you can measure coordinates with respect to this "origin.